# How to map multiple columns to one field using @Column annotation?

Tags: java, mysql

As a result from MySQL I have three fields (for example **link1**, **link2** and **link3**) and I want to store only one of them in **link** variable depending on some rules. This is the code now for a single field:

```
@Column(name = "link1")
@JsonProperty("link")
private String link;
```

I have to compate values in **link1**, **link2** and **link3** and decide which of them to store in **link**. How can I do it?

Comment: The easy way : use 3 attributes `link1`, `link2`, `link3` and implement the logic in a getter `getLink()` which returns one of those attributes.

Comment: What @Arnaud had suggested is the most appropriate, clean and understandable way to achieve that, or you can write your own custom annotation to carry out this logic.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, thank you for the good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ArnaudDenoyelle mentioned the easiest way is to use 3 attributes `link1`, `link2`, `link3` and implement the logic in a getter `getLink()` which returns one of those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you cannot read multiple fields and store in one variable using the standard `@Column` annotation.

But there is a workaround using native queries. The Java Persistence Query Language has the [`CONCAT()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_string_fun) function. 
So you can write `CONCAT(CONCAT(e.link1, e.link2), e.link3)`